# No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21 available for offline mode Error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. It will be useful to people after I Den. If you can tell the reason, you will be very helpful. thanks

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'App Name'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21 available for offline mode.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Story Maker'.    
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
    
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21.
Required by:
    project :
Cause 1: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21 available for offline mode.
Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21 available for offline mode.
Cause 3: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21 available for offline mode.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 5s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got Gradle in *offline mode*, which means it doesn't try to check for updates to dependencies etc (makes builds quicker) but it also can't download anything that isn't already in the cache.

You can enable/disable it in the settings, easiest way (and maybe how you accidentally (?) turned it on in the first place) is to use this button in the popout `Gradle` panel:

[image]

Just make sure that's **not** enabled and try building. Make sure you have an internet connection too!